# Technology to display a 3D Map like Google Maps

Tags: javascript, html, web-development, maps, angular

I would like to create a Progressive Web App that has an indoor map of a building. I have floor plans to serve as the basis for the map. I am new to creating Hybrid apps so I am not sure where to start with this. At the moment I am hoping to use the Ionic framework for cross platform nice UI stuff and use Capacitor (or Cordova) to give me access to native functions. This means my app will be JavaScript based. I might use AngularJS but I have not dealt with any of these frameworks before.

Considering this context, where could I start with displaying a 3D map? How do I create the 3D map from a 2D floor plan and how does that become something a user can interact with? Is there a library for this or do I have to use WebGL or pure HTML5 and start from scratch? Is there something that allows me to create a 3D map and then allow interaction with it in a JavaScript context?

If any more background information is required, let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: I found Leaflet, that seems promising.

Comment: Any thoughts, anyone?